# Of at the beginning of a paragraph

Tags: prepositions

Is it okay to begin a paragraph with the preposition **of**?

Of the three available departments at Holiday Stores, I am interested in the fashion one. ...

Comment: **Of** course it's okay to begin....

Comment: Yes, but you need a good reason for it.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure there are many books that begin with "of" in the same structure you have used here

Answer (score 1):

There are no special rules of grammar for the first sentences of a paragraph. There may be rhetorical suggestions, but they are nothing more than suggestions.

There are rules of grammar for sentences and clauses though those rules have many exceptions. The basic structure of an indicative clause is subject + verb. But it is certainly permissible to start with a prepositional phrase.

> Of all the men I met there, he was …

The prepositional phrase is clarifying the clause’s subject “he.”

> With great effort, she pushed through the crowd.

The prepositional phrase is modifying the verb.

If it is good enough for a clause, it is good enough for a mere paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

**Using *of* at the beginning of a paragraph?**

There seems to be no rules of grammar against the use of starting a paragraph with the use of using the preposition [of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of) at the start of a paragraph.

Personally, I would not start an opening paragraph with this usage, but that is just myself. In the past I have used **”of”** at the beginning of paragraphs, especially when making reference to material preciously mentioned in the work I was writing about.

> *Of all the above things previously mentioned, ...*